# Convert python list of dictionaries to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
     fruit_list = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "fruit": {
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "name": "Banana",
                    "origin": "Brazil"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "fruit": {
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "name": "Banana",
                    "plural_name": "Bananas",
                    "origin": "Africa"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "fruit": {
                    "parent_id": 2,
                    "name": "Orange",
                    "origin": "Africa"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "fruit": {
                    "parent_id": 2,
                    "name": "Orange",
                    "origin": "Africa"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "fruit": {
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "plural_name": "Apples",
                    "origin": "Africa"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "fruit": {
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "plural_name": "Apples",
                    "origin": "Brazil"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I want to create a pandas dataframe out of it that looks like this:

```
parent_id    Brazil    Africa
---------------------------------
1            Banana    Banana
1                      Bananas
2            Orange    Orange
3            Apple     Apple
3            Apples    Apples
```

It should be able to put out the plural name and add the parent id for that fruit. The problem I am having is that I am only able to get out the "normal" name.
Anyone have any tips on doing this in a dynamic and elegant way? 
Maybe getting the fruits based on their parent ids?

Comment: i dont think u have orange in Brazil

Comment: haha that does not matter... It is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {}
for fruit in fruit_list:
    parent_id = str(fruit['fruit']['parent_id'])
    if parent_id not in data.keys():
        data[parent_id] = dict()

    if 'plural_name' in fruit['fruit'].keys():
        if parent_id + '_p' not in data.keys():
            data[parent_id + '_p'] = dict()

        data[parent_id + '_p']['parent_id'] = parent_id
        data[parent_id + '_p'][fruit['fruit']['origin']] = fruit['fruit']['plural_name']

        data[parent_id]['parent_id'] = parent_id
        data[parent_id][fruit['fruit']['origin']] = fruit['fruit']['name']
    else:
        data[parent_id]['parent_id'] = parent_id
        data[parent_id][fruit['fruit']['origin']] = fruit['fruit']['name']

list_of_data = []
for key, value in data.items():
    list_of_data.append(value)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_data)
```

using the data provided the output is

```
>>> df
  parent_id  Brazil   Africa
0         1  Banana   Banana
1         1     NaN  Bananas
2         2     NaN   Orange
3         3   Apple    Apple
4         3  Apples   Apples
```

NaN can later be replaced to an empty string with

```py
df.fillna('')
```

Comment: I am trying to test your solution, but I keep getting : TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
on  data[parent_id] = dict() the first 5 lines. I dont think you can assign parent id like that to the list, if that is what you are trying to do?

Comment: It seems that you name a variable `dict` which overwrites the default name that is the dictionary constructor. Change the dict name of your variable to something else. The code is working fine on its own with just the `fruit_list` added.

Comment: Oh gosh. That was embarrassing. Thanks! It works now. Thanks :)!